# Bot not responding to button click

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to create an anti-raid bot that will have 3 buttons, one of those is a lockdown button I created it but it's not sending the final response message

It returns an error - `AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'response'`

and shows `This interaction failed`

Here is my code -

```
class Lockdown(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(label="Lockdown", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def lockdown(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        for channel in button.guild.channels:
            if isinstance(channel, discord.TextChannel):
                await channel.set_permissions(button.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
        await interaction.response.send_message("All text channels are locked", ephemeral=True)

@bot.command()
async def lockdown(ctx):
    view = Lockdown()
    await ctx.send("Click lockdown to lock all text channels", view=view)
```

Comment: Swap the button and interaction parameters. The order was changed in later versions. So, `self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply switch the `button` and `interaction` arguments around.

```py
class Lockdown(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(label="Lockdown", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def lockdown(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        for channel in button.guild.channels:
            if isinstance(channel, discord.TextChannel):
                await channel.set_permissions(button.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
        await interaction.response.send_message("All text channels are locked", ephemeral=True)
```